# Show alternating images for changing ViewModel states

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, mvvm

For different user interfaces I want to show an image depending on a state of a ViewModel object.

For example:

I have a database connection, if connected, I want to show a green database image, if not connected I want to display a red database image.

In the ViewModel there is a `bool` that represents the state.

Possibilities are:

- Having two images in the view (with a converter InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter for the red image), which are at the same place, actually just showing one of them.
- Binding for `Image source` (but I do not want to set this in my ViewModel)
- Some sort of selector?

This state depending image can be more often of use, e.g. in a `TreeView` as `ItemImage`.

Is there a more clever way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a valueconverter like so:

```
public class BoolToImageConverter: DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{

    public BitmapImage TrueImage
    {
        get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(TrueImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TrueImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty TrueImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TrueImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(BoolToImageConverter), null);


    public BitmapImage FalseImage
    {
        get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(FalseImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FalseImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty FalseImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FalseImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(BoolToImageConverter), null);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? TrueImage : FalseImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var img = (BitmapImage)value;
        return img.UriSource.AbsoluteUri == TrueImage.UriSource.AbsoluteUri;
    }

}
```

and in XAML

```
<my:BoolToImageConverter x:Key="converterName" FalseImage="{StaticResource falseImage}" TrueImage="{StaticResource trueImage}"/>
```

Comment: I really like that, as it is easy to use with enum-like states, not just bools, the xaml keeps concise that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with solely with data triggers. Here's a sample from one of my projects for a button that changes it's image depending on whether or not the form is in an Edit mode or not:

```
<Button x:Name="EditOrSaveJob"
                    Width="32"
                    Height="32"
                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image>
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/AAAA;component/Resources/Images/edit.png" />
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Edit Order" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/AAAA;component/Resources/Images/32_save.png" />
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Save Order" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: An all-XAML solution looks very good to me, as this problem is solely View-specific. Thank you!

Comment: I will definitly use this in some cases, but I can only accept one answer, please excuse me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be using converter (class that implements IValueConverter):

```
class ImageStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(  Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter,    CultureInfo culture)    
    {
        bool state = (bool) value;
        return state ? "img1.png" : "img2.png";
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML write binding like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

Object myConverter is declared somewhere in Resources section.

Comment: The reason I don't like this approach is that it isn't reusable and you end up with a new type every time you need to toggle a new image.  You could make it a little better by using virtual/abstract properties instead of hard coded string constants.

Comment: Thought about some converter like this one, but I want my image file references in the XAML, nowhere else. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: i wanted to merely show how wpf converters work, of course in real code you should expose properties for every image file reference